# Invisible keyframes and broken rigitbody

Tags: animation

I am trying to animate basketball throw and i need to add keyframes for the ball. But every time i try to do it I can't see "diamond" icons on timeline. Please help me I am new to blender[image]

Also I'd be glad to know how to animate it properly because even with invisible keyframes method from this video doesn't work (https://youtu.be/cLt8o_8flu4?t=126) also I recorded example how I broke everything (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1moYgPX9GtIGBllG8nFvux5x7aFa3n4Lx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: On the video you can see keyframes but that was before I deleted all of them in order to try animating again

Comment: Hi there :) . Hover your pointer over the timeline and holding the middle mouse button try dragging the timeline downwards...If still the problem persists try sharing your blend file

Comment: Thank you very much. I scrolled for couple of minutes but I finaly found them. Can anyone give a piece of advice how to show them on the top of timeline?

Comment: Can u share an image of where the keyframe was?